# How to draw a 3d Teechart which have cubes in it

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, teechart

I have data like this(x_pos, y_pos, z_pos, Length, height, depth). I need to draw cube by using this information. Can any one help me to do draw Teechart for this. give me some sample code for this.

Comment: Which development environment or language are you using?

Comment: I am using C# language with Visual studio

Comment: which sort of application: winforms, webforms, wpf, silverlight, windows phone, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, etc.? Thanks.

Comment: Many apologies for the delayed reply. See the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it with custom canvas drawing using the *Cube(Rectangle r, int z0, int z1)* method in TChart's *AfterDraw* event, for example:

```
void tChart1_AfterDraw(object sender, Steema.TeeChart.Drawing.Graphics3D g)
{
  int x = 100;
  int y = 100;
  int z = 0;
  int width = 50;
  int height = 50;
  int depth= 10;

  DrawCube(x, y, z, width, height, depth, g);
}

private void DrawCube(int x, int y, int z, int width, int height, int depth, Steema.TeeChart.Drawing.Graphics3D g)
{
  Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
  g.Cube(r, z, z + depth);
}
```